# I am trying to get metabox image with custom size

Tags: images

I am trying to get meta box image with custom image size. 
i used this code to get image but image is not displaying.

```
<?php
    $img_src = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'project_options', true );
    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_src, 'size_300_190');
?>

<img src="<?php $img_src['mobile_image']; ?>" alt="" />
```

and if i remove this line

```
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_src, 'size_300_190');
```

then image get visible.

> I gave this custom size before uploading image.

Comment: How did you create the image size? What were the arguments you passed to `add_image_size()`?

Comment: For your code to work there would have to be (at least) one additional closing PHP tag-- `?>`. As written, you will get a an error on the third line.

Comment: What's the value of the above `project_options` post meta?

Comment: Hello @bungeshea, yes i have used the.
`add_image_size( 'size_300_190', 300, 190, true );`

Comment: Value is `['mobile_image']`